# why to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Tags: c#, .net

why to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol and 
if we set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol value how and when it is works any one please explain

Comment: Doesn't `This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only; existing connections are not changed.` from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.100).aspx) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As MSDN describes:

> This property selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only; existing connections are not changed...

For more detail visit following links:

[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property (Currect Version of .Net Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property (.NET Framework 4)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.100).aspx)